# How to setup Google Oauth with passport for android and ios without duplicate endpoints in NestJs

Tags: node.js, nestjs, passport.js, passport-google-oauth, nestjs-passport

So basically Im trying to setup Google OAuth for both ios and android but Im currently stuck, because the clientId and clientSecret is different for ios and android.

So when creating the Strategy class that extends PassportStrategy I have to define the client secret and client id inside the constructor. Is there a away to make this dynamic without having any code duplication?

GoogleStrategy

```
@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'google') {
  constructor() {
    super({
      clientID: '', // dynamic for ios and android
      clientSecret: '',  // dynamic for ios and android
      callbackURL: '',
      scope: ['email', 'profile'],
    });
  }
  async validate(
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
    profile: any,
    done: VerifyCallback,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const { name, emails, photos } = profile;
    done(null, profile);
  }
}
```

GoogleController

```
@Controller('google-auth')
export class GoogleAuthController {
  constructor(private readonly googleAuthService: GoogleAuthService) {}

  @Get('login')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  login(@Param('platform') platform: string, @Req() req) {
    // Query params to switch between android and ios
    // e.g platform=android or platform=ios
    
    //But what now? The strategy get initiated inside the module
  }

  @Get('redirect')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  redirect(@Req() req) {}

  @Get('status')
  status() {}

  @Get('logout')
  logout() {}
}
```

GoogleModule

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, GoogleStrategy], //How to use this strategy for both ios and android?
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The OAuth ClientId is different for iOS and Android:
[image]

Comment: Why is the id and secret different for each client side? I haven't done much mobile work, but your server should be client agnostic, right?

Comment: Yes as far as is possible. But in this case I have to differentiate between ios and android cause of the client IDs(That I had to create inside the google cloud console)

Comment: But why do you have two different IDs? Why did you go with a separate ID per client type? Why not just send everything through the same server and have the server make use of one client ID?

Answer (score 0):

We can do it by creating custom guard and use that in out controller.ts file

> controller.ts file

```
  @UseGuards(FacebookGuard, AuthGuard(‘facebook’))
```

> FacebookGuard.ts file

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from ‘@nestjs/common’;
    import { ClientAppService } from ‘../clientApp/clientApp.service’;
    import { Injectable } from ‘@nestjs/common’;
    import { FacebookStrategy } from ‘../auth/facebook.strategy’;
    
    type Provider = {
      providerType: string;
      providerKey: string;
      providerSecret: string;
      callBackUrl: string;
    };
    
    @Injectable()
    export class FacebookGuard implements CanActivate {
      /**
       * Constructor
       * @param {ClientAppService} clientAppService
       */
      constructor(readonly clientAppService: ClientAppService) {}
    
      async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const data = await this.clientAppService.getProviderDetails(
          request.query.appKey,
          ‘facebook’,
        );
        const providerData = data.providerId as any;
         new FacebookStrategy(
          providerData.providerKey,
          providerData.providerSecret,
          providerData.callBackUrl + ‘/’ + request.query.appKey + 
           ‘/callback’,
        );
        return true;
      }
    }
```